# Append two byte arrays to one byte array using VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to append two bytes to one byte using VB.NET

This is my code,

```
Dim bytes(5) As Byte
bytes(0) = devid 'variable byte
bytes(1) = &H3
bytes(2) = x1 'variable byte
bytes(3) = x2 'variable byte
bytes(4) = &H0
bytes(5) = &H1

Dim bytescrc() As Byte = CRC(bytes) ' call to crc funtion and store 2 bytes output is { &HFF, &HB5 }

Dim bytesful() As Byte = {bytes, bytescrc}
```

Error msg is *Value of type 'Byte()' cannot be converted to 'Byte'.*

How to append `bytes` 6 byte array and `bytescrc` 2 byte array to `bytesful` byte array.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of specific ways this could be done but a little LINQ makes it easy:

```
Dim bytesful() As Byte = bytes.Concat(bytescrc).ToArray()
```

`Concat` will create a single `IEnumerable(Of T)` by concatenating two `IEnumerable(Of T)` objects and `ToArray` creates a new array from that single list.

Answer (score 7):

Adding the [Array.CopyTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Array.CopyTo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method to the one proposed by `jmcilhinney`, in case performace is something to consider.
In the case presented it wouldn't matter, but should the number of elements increase (in thousands) and the operation iterated, the result could be quite different.

```
Dim bytesful((bytes.Length + bytescrc.Length) - 1) As Byte

bytes.CopyTo(bytesful, 0)
bytescrc.CopyTo(bytesful, bytes.Length)
```

[Enumerable.Concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) has the advantage that it's more *readable* an you can add even more arrays in one single line:

```
Dim bytesful() As Byte = bytes.Concat(bytescrc).Concat(SomethingElse).ToArray()
```